# ListView - how to disable element turning into gray on mouse hover

Tags: windows, listview, windows-store-apps, mousehover, modern-ui

On Windows 8 Store App I need simple list without any click/hover action. I created ListView but I dont't know how to disable element background turning into gray after mousehover. (Element has TextBox and TextBlock)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ElementTemplate}" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" SelectionMode="None" />
```

SelectionMode="None" disabled selecting, but how to turn off changing element background color to gray when mouse is over element?

Comment: I have added fragment of my xaml with listview

Comment: I think it is "ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush".  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208807) shows you how to modify them.